# Mongo jackson mapper remove by id result

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm removing an object by its id using mongo jackson mapper:

```
WriteResult<Restaurant, String> writeResult = restaurantCollection.removeById(restaurantIdToDelete);
String restaurantId = writeResult.getSavedId();
```

and I'm getting

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: No objects to return
```

since the object doesn't exist anymore the system cannot retrieve its id AND/OR the getSavedId() method has been implemented only for saving operations.

How am I supposed to know if the remove operation went smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:

```
public String removeRestaurant(String restaurantIdToDelete){

    String restaurantId = null;

    WriteResult<Restaurant, String> writeResult = restaurantCollection.removeById(restaurantIdToDelete);

    if(writeResult != null)
        restaurantId = restaurantIdToDelete; 

    return restaurantId;

}
```

So in theory if something goes wrong either WriteResult should be null or a MongoException would have been thrown... not sure 100% though.